# Threaded view on discussion board: is it possible to sort by reverse chronological order

Tags: 2010, list-view, discussion-board

I've tried to figure out how to configure the threaded view of a discussion board (Sharepoint 2010) to sort the thread by reverse chronological order (most recent post first). No success so far. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this helpful post when trying to sort the discussion board.
The problem with this method is that in the 'flat' view  - discussions having no replies are not shown. Anyone came across with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work right. I thought it was a good question. How the view should be set up is:

**Columns:**

> - Threaded(threading)

**Sort:**

> - First sort by: Threading -> Show items in descending order
> - Then sort by: Created -> Show items in descending order
> - Uncheck "Sort only by specified criteria"

**Folders:**

> - Show all items without folders
> - Show this view: In folders of content type "Discussion"

This setup worked for me.

Comment: If it worked for you, mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thanks this really got me out of a bind.

I do have a question tho. I have created multi views for a discussion board using custom discussion board categories, for each view I have tailored the view to only display topics of that category.  However, now regardless of which category tile is selected the last view set in the webpart is used by all categories and not the specific one for that category.  Im stuck any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are supposed to post answer here, you can either put comments, or if not possible, create a new question